# Navigation lost hover when media size shrinks

Tags: html, css

I used a tutorial to build a responsive navigation menu which was working great here:
http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386b09/giotto/index.html

I added a logo and some other elements and have lost the hover when the media size changes as seen here:
http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386b09/giotto2/index.html

I have have a feeling it's somewhere here but cant tell what it might be:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav hidden">
```

CSS:

```
ul.nav
{ list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position: absolute;}

ul.nav li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
z-index: 999;}`
```

I can post the entire HTML/CSS if needed.

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem. What browser and OS are you using? Can you give more detail?

Comment: do post the entire css for future reference as the part you have posted is not the problematic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `#header` and `#navbar` have hardcoded `height` values and the `.nav` elements, while the `#menu` is `float:left` due to the `nav` class it has.

You need to set `height:auto` for the `#header` and `#navbar` in the mobile version and also either add `overflow:hidden` on the `#navbar` or remove the `float:left` from the `.nav`.

---

So the actual problem was that the `.full-width` element was overlaid on the open menu and it was intercepting the mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

There is this rule in line 81 of your CSS for width below 759px :

```
ul.nav {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
```

And there is no hover rule which changes that `diplay: none`. So you should add this rule directly under the one above:

```
#navbar:hover ul.nav {
    display: block;
}
```